# How to check whether the input is int or string

Tags: c#

If the input is numerical then run `numPalindrome()`.

If the input is alphabetical then run `strPalindrome()`.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.Write("Enter your Input: ");
    var input = Console.ReadLine();
    if (What to do?????)
    {
        strPalindrome();
    }
    else
    {
        numPalindrome();
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe use [`int.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse)?

Comment: [int.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse) might helpful

Comment: Int.TryParse() but could use RegEx.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if(int.TryParse(input, out int value))
{
  // input is an int, call numPalindrome(value)
}
else
{
  // input is not an int, call strPalindrome()
}
```

Comment: ^^That. The only way to know if it is a int, is to try to parse it to int. | Just be warned, that value is always set - TryParse defaults to setting it to 0 in case the parsing fails. So do not use it by accident.

Comment: @Christopher - that's correct. Thank you for adding this point.

Comment: `int.Parse` will of course also accept negtive number. If you don't want these, use `uint.TryParse`.